# HTML Canvas does not refresh

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Hi there I am going crazy (my wife says it will be a short trip!) I have just started with Canvas and I cannot get the canvas to show intermediate results.  I have read many articles here but those articles refer to all kinds of "things" and nothing to the basics.  Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="RoomCanvas" width="300" height="200">
<!-- ************************************* -->
<!-- The wall is always here               -->
<!-- ************************************* --> 
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>

<script>
var c = document.getElementById("RoomCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 200);
alert("clear");
doWall("green");
alert("try");
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 200);
alert("wall");
doWall("purple");
    
function doWall(theColor){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(0, 200);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 44;
  ctx.strokeStyle = theColor;
  ctx.stroke();
return;
}



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

```js
var c = document.getElementById("RoomCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 200);
alert("clear");
doWall("green");
alert("try");
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 200);
alert("wall");
doWall("purple");

function doWall(theColor) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(0, 200);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 44;
  ctx.strokeStyle = theColor;
  ctx.stroke();
  return;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <canvas id="RoomCanvas" width="300" height="200">
<!-- ************************************* -->
<!-- The wall is always here               -->
<!-- ************************************* --> 
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

The green line never shows.  The canvas only "shows" when the program stops running.  I have tried to take superfluous code out of the example.  Basically I want the program to draw three lines.  When the fourth line is drawn I want to erase line 1.  My problem no lines show until the program quits and then only the last 3 lines show, the user never sees any other lines.

Thank you, your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your function just draws a line over the same coordinates as the previous line. You are also using `clearRect` to "erase" the green line right after drawing it and then drawing a purple one. It happens so fast you don't see it of course.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using alert let's try with a setInterval that will call a draw function every 500 milliseconds...

Here is the code:

```js
const c = document.getElementById("RoomCanvas");
const ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var color = "green"

function doWall(theColor){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(100, 100);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 8;
  ctx.strokeStyle = theColor;
  ctx.stroke();
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  doWall(color)
  color = (color == "green"? "red": "green")
}

setInterval(draw, 500)
```

```html
<canvas id="RoomCanvas" width="100" height="100">
</canvas>
```

---

Same code now with more param in the doWall function

```js
const c = document.getElementById("RoomCanvas");
const ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var color = "green"
var x = 10
var y = 90

function doWall(x, y, theColor){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(x, y);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 8;
  ctx.strokeStyle = theColor;
  ctx.stroke();
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  doWall(x, y, color)
  color = (color == "green"? "red": "green")
  x = ++x % c.width
}

setInterval(draw, 100)
```

```html
<canvas id="RoomCanvas" width="100" height="100">
</canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that is "kinda" what I was looking for..  In the real world the program may wait for 10 minutes while the green line is being displayed..  I am going to try your solution and clear and reset the interval when the line has to change colors.  Any other ideas?

Comment: You can use `setInterval` or `setTimeout` to do a wait ... ideas: ask new questions with more details when you get stuck